# Dell XPS 15 (9570), TB16 dock, and mixed DPI dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, xrandr, emacs, hdpi

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell XPS 15 (9570) with the 4K display. I am trying to use the TB16 dock to connect to an external display at work that is 1920x1080 and I'm facing the seemingly comming "hiDPI" issues.

The xrandr commands [found here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Multiple_displays) work well and I can setup the external monitor to be reasonably-sized while also running my 4K display at full-res. However, as soon as I scale with xrandr I get a flickering mouse on my main display.emacs

Here's the script I run to set up my external display:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set up frame buffer (add up the mode OR scale-from parameters below)
xrandr --fb 7680x2160 &&

# Set up laptop monitor
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 3840x2160 --rate 60 --primary &&

# Set up external display(s)
# My configuration only has a 1080p display to the right of my laptop
xrandr --output DP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale-from 3840x2160 --panning 3840x2160+3840+0 --right-of eDP-1
```

The solution to this is [found here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358992/cursor-flickers-with-xrandr-scaling)

That works great, so now I have seemingly solves the HiDPI + LoDPI external display problem and the mouse flickering problem. And then I open emacs... and weird graphical glitches start to occur. The cursor causes characters to disappear permanently until I change lines, etc.

Any ideas of how to fix this last issue with emacs?

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved the problem before I posted this, but since I spent so many hours figuring this out today I figured I would post the question and answer it so that it may help others that stumble here in the future:

This issue seems to go away if you install emacs26 (which appears to implement double-buffering which may help mitigate this issue).

I uninstalled emacs25 and installed emacs26 and no issues yet...